# Anybody know what might be causing my laser readings to behave like this? [video]

Tags: navigation, odometry, laser

[image: Rosanswers logo]

https://youtu.be/vQJC-mlnRKY

In the video I move the robot, and the laser readings seem to move along with the robot, when in fact they should be more stationary.
I then increase the delay on the /scan topic, and I get a really thick wall, in the direction in which the robot is moving.

Any idea what might cause it?
It seems that algorithms like gmapping are producing a pretty decent map.

I did a tf view_frame, and the tf's are all publishing at about 5hz, the robot is defined in a urdf.

Thank you in advance!

Here is the tf_view file, the laser scan comes from veldyne: [image: C:\fakepath\frames.png]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/266413/anybody-know-what-might-be-causing-my-laser-readings-to-behave-like-this?-%5Bvideo%5D/) by [Cristian11235](https://answers.ros.org/users/27564/cristian11235/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2017-07-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2017-07-14**:
Could you post the view_frames.py output?

**Comment by [Cristian11235](https://answers.ros.org/users/27564/cristian11235/) on 2017-07-14**:
Ive updated the original post with the view frames output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like your odometry is scaled incorrectly; notice how the laser scans move, but only about half as far as the robot moves.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cristian11235](https://answers.ros.org/users/27564/cristian11235/) on 2017-07-14**:
The issue was indeed the odometry was scaled exactly how you said, by half of what  the robot moves at.

I had changed the motor controlled/ encoders and did not update the code to properly reflect this.

Thank you